# VueJS - Popular select com dados da API

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

Estou com problemas para popular uma select com os dados que tenho como retorno de uma API. Estou usando Vue.

Segue códigos:

Meu HTML esta assim:

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma conta</option>
  <option v-for="account in accounts" :key="account" :value="account">{{ account }}</option>
</select>
```

Estou fazendo a chama da API com axios:

```
data() {
  accounts: []
},

methods: {
  async getAccounts() {
   await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:4000/api/accounts')
    .then(res => {
      // console.log(res)
      res.map(account => {
        this.accounts.push(account)
        // console.log(this.accounts)
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // console.log(err)
      M.toast({html: 'Houve um erro ao buscar contas.', classes: 'rounded red darken-1', outDuration: 1000})
    })
  }
},

created() {
  this.getAccounts()
}
```

Mas quando carrega a página o select não é populado. Se eu tiro o comentário do console.log(this.accounts) depois do push, ele mostra no console os valores dentro do array certinho.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

#### EDIT

Atualizando o código depois de algumas alterações, tanto no vue quanto na API que faço consumo. E dando algumas explicações referente alguns pontos que o @guastallaigor levantou.

Primeiro as questionamentos da resposta do @guastallaigor:

```
1 - data () sempre deve ser uma função e ela deve retornar um objeto

    R: O código esta com o return no data, é que no momento de fazer a 
     pergunta eu não selecionei tudo, dei ctrl+c e ctrl+v, eu fui 
     pegando por parte do código e jogando aqui, ai nessa posso ter 
     deixado passar o return.

2 - Verifique se a maneira que você está utilizando o axios está 
    correta, pois está divergente da documentação e da maneira que 
    costumo utilizar/ver. (axios.get - no meu esta $axios.$get)

    R: Estou utilizando desta forma, porque não estou utilizando o 
       VueJS puro, estou utilizando o Nuxt, que é um "framework" (não 
       sei se da pra chama-lo assim), construído em cima do Vue, é bem 
       interessante, e nele ja vem o axios configurado. Aí no Nuxt pra 
       usar o axios devo dar um this.$axios.$get por exemplo, ai não 
       necessito dar import no axios também.

3/4 - Verifique se a resposta da API é de fato um array / Verifique se 
      a API está correta e voltando o JSON da maneira esperada;

    R: A API esta retornando um array de objetos da forma que preciso 
       no front, agora não necessito mais do map ou forEach. Depois 
       que alterei o retorno da API agora só preciso do   
       this.accounts = res, e ele ja me retorna corretamente, verifico 
       isso pelo console.log(res)

5 - Utilize o :key com uma chave única, ou a chave do próprio v-for

    R: A API me retorna um array de objetos, com, conta e 
       descricao_conta. Dentro das options, devo mostrar "conta - 
       descricao_conta", então como tenho o código da conta, no :key, 
       eu jogo accounts.conta, e não necessito da chave do próprio 
       objeto.
```

Agora irei colocar como esta o código do meu front:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma conta</option>
  <option
      v-for="account in accounts"
      :key="account.conta" 
      :value="account.conta">
      {{ account.conta }} - {{ account.descricao_conta }}
 </option>
</select>


data() {
    return {
        selected: null,
        accounts: []
    }
}


methods: {
  async getAccounts() {
    let self = this
    await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:4000/api/accounts')
      .then(res => {
        // console.log(res)
        self.accounts = res
        // console.log(self.accounts)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // console.log(err)
        M.toast({html: 'Houve um erro ao buscar as contas.', classes: 'rounded red darken-1', outDuration: 1000})
      })
  }
}


async created() {
  await this.getAccounts()
  console.log(this.accounts)
}
```

O console.log que coloquei dentro do created(), ele retorna a variável accounts preenchida com os dados da API corretamente, mas o select continua vazio. Ou seja, quando chamo a função que busca os dados na API, ele realmente popula a variável accounts, mas não popula o select.

Comment: como está `console.log(this.accounts)` antes do `this.accounts.push(account)` ? `[]` ou `undefined`?

Comment: Ele não retorna dado nenhum. Retorna [__ob__: Observer]

Comment: Alterei a API, e nela já configurei os dados para virem em Array do jeito que preciso, então no Vue só estou atribuindo o res para accounts

Comment: Mas mesmo assim continua sem funcionar. Tentei criar uma variável fora do axios para armazenar o this, mas mesmo assim não foi

Comment: Porque não coloca tudo em `created()`? deixando assim `async created ()`

Comment: Tentei dessa forma mas também não funcionou :/

Comment: Não sei onde pode estar errado

Comment: Dentro da função getAccounts ao invés de setar o valor para variável accounts, eu coloquei um return res. E dentro de data, onde declaro a variável accoounts atribuí a ela por padrão o método assim:


data: {
    accounts: getAccounts
}


Mas mesmo assim nao funciona

Comment: this.getAccounts()

Comment: e assim `this.accounts = res` ?

Comment: Assim mesmo que estou tentando

Comment: `{{ accounts }}` mostra o resultado do `res` ?

Comment: Se dou um console.log(this.accounts) dentro do método getAccounts() ele retorna os valores corretos, mas, se dou console.log(this.accounts) no created(), depois de chamar o this.getAccounts(), ele retorna vazio

Comment: Sim, foi o que eu imaginei mas tenta esses códigos dentro do `async created()`, sem `methods`

Comment: Tentei desta forma e ele não traz nem os console.log

Comment: A resposta da API está correta? O `console.log(res)` mostra que os dados estão voltando da maneira esperada?

Comment: @Gabriel Eis os pontos que você tem que testar, `this` está funcionando dentro do `async`? se não funciona, nem vai gravar os dados pois não existe comunicação com `data()`

Comment: Oque te dá se colocares `console.log(typeof res, res);` onde tens `// console.log(res)`?

Answer (score 2):

Vou tentar ajudar com base no que eu entendi e as suas respostas no comentário.

Há alguns detalhes que podem estar influenciando o seu problema.

**1. `data ()` sempre deve ser uma função e ela deve retornar um objeto;**

O seu código está assim:

```
data() {
  accounts: []
},
```

Quando deveria estar assim:

```
data () {
  return {
    accounts: []
  }
},
```

Ou assim:

```
data: () => ({
  accounts: []
}),
```

**2. Verifique se a maneira que você está utilizando o `axios` está correta, pois está divergente da documentação e da maneira que costumo utilizar/ver;**

Você está utilizando assim:

```
this.$axios.$get
```

Eu costumo utilizar/ver assim:

```
axios.get // ou mudando a nomenclatura
```

E importando assim, geralmente em seu `mainjs`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

**3. Verifique se a resposta da API é de fato um `array`;**

Você utiliza a resposta diretamente com a função `map`

```
res.map(account => {
```

Quando se a resposta for um objeto, ocorrerá um erro. Outro ponto é que se for de fato um array, pode ser atribuído assim:

```
this.accounts = res
```

Ou assim, realizando a cópia:

```
this.accounts = [...res]
```

Não havendo a necessidade do `map`, pois o `map` ainda retornará um `array`, que você não está utilizando. Se não desejar utilizar assim, e de fato com a função `push`, poderia utilizar um `forEach`.

**4. Verifique se a API está correta e voltando o JSON da maneira esperada;**

Não há o que explicar neste caso, apenas verifique o retorno com `console.log`.

**5. Utilize o `:key` com uma chave única, ou a chave do próprio `v-for`;**

No caso, colocar o objeto inteiro (supondo que é um objeto) dentro do atributo `:key` não é aconselhável. Caso seja um objeto, e não tenha um `id` para ele, coloque assim:

```
<option v-for="(account, key) in accounts" :key="key" :value="account">{{ account }}</option>
```

**Exemplo:**

Iniciando um novo projeto, e utilizando o `axios` da maneira que mostra a documentação, bem como alguns pontos que eu disse, juntamente com o mockAPI, há este resultado funcional, preenchendo o select corretamente:

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="stackoverflow">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma conta</option>
      <option v-for="account in accounts" :key="account" :value="account">{{ account.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
const url = 'http://5af0e90b954a1000145c4c65.mockapi.io/accounts'

export default {
  name: 'Stackoverflow',
  data: () => ({
    accounts: []
  }),
  methods: {
    async getAccounts () {
      await axios.get(url)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          this.accounts = [...res.data]
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          // M.toast({html: 'Houve um erro ao buscar contas.', classes: 'rounded red darken-1', outDuration: 1000})
        })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getAccounts()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela força @guastallaigor. Vou editar minha pergunta, pois alterei o retorno que a API manda pro vue. E explicar alguns pontos que vc levantou com sua resposta.

Comment: quanto ao `this.$axios`, ele possivelmente deve está fazendo um Mixin para injetar o mesmo (ou pelo menos, eu espero que esteja).